# How do you suppress property replacement when creating a project from an archetype?

Tags: maven-2, maven, archetypes

I'm trying to create an archtype for a simple project, this project contains some ssl certs that i'd like to includes as resources in the archtype so when the project gets created those certs will be part of the project. My problem is that maven is trying to do a property replacement on those certs when creating a project with the archetype. Is there anyway to tell maven not to do the property replacement?
I've already tried the following:

```
    <resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.xml</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
```

in my prototype POM.xml. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem exactly is (are your certificates xml files??) but my guess is that it is related to the fact that most of non binary content of an archetype is processed by velocity during creation (see [ARCHETYPE-90](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-90) about this problem).

A workaround is to configure the [create-from-project](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html) mojo to have file unfiltered by default using:

```
-Darchetype.filteredExtentions=ext1,ext2,...
```

It sets the extensions for files that will be filtered and the default value include `java`, `xml`, `txt`, `vm`, `groovy`, `jsp`, `gsp`, `vm` and `properties`. So exclude `xml` from this list if you don't want `xml` to be filtered.

Another option would be to specify custom metadata for your archetype, something like this in `src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor name="myarchetype">
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet filtered="false" encoding="UTF-8">
      <directory>src/foobar</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.xml</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

See [this page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-metadata.html) for more details on archetype metadata.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem trying to use ${basedir} in archetype-resources/pom.xml but it was being replaced when the archetype ran to create the project and so pointed to the wrong directory.

The fix is simple.  Just use \${basedir} instead.  This escapes the $ sign and prevents maven from replacing it when the archetype is run.  Then your generated pom.xml file will contain ${basedir} instead of the directory that the archetype ran from.